# Creating a registry with PySimpleGUI but I can't create the columns with the values ​of the keys

Tags: pandas, pysimplegui

#error creating table with desired column

```
from PySimpleGUI import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

# Layout
sg.theme('Reddit')
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Ticker: '), sg.Input(key='Ticker')],
    [sg.Text('Quantidade de Papéis: '), sg.Input(key='Qtd_de_papeis')],
    [sg.Text('Valor: '), sg.Input(key='Valor_pago')],
    [sg.Text('Data:'), sg.Input(key='Data')],
    [sg.Button('Adicionar'), sg.Button('Cancelar')]
]
# Janela
window = sg.Window('Tela de Cadastro', layout)
# Ler os eventos


while True:
    events, values = window.read()
    if events == (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancelar'):
        break
    if events == 'Adicionar':
        columns = list(values.keys())
        rows = list(values.values())
        print(rows)
        print(columns)
        df.to_csv('registro.csv', sep=';', mode='a', index=False)
df_new = pd.read_csv('registro.csv', sep=';')
window.close()
print(df_new)
```

#I wanted to know if there is a way to assign columns or will it be necessary to create variables

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it work for you.
Here, it will create new CSV file when first record added.
You can check if file exist or not.
If exist, you can set `headings = False` before your event loop.

```py
from PySimpleGUI import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd


fields = {
    'Ticker'        : 'Ticker:',
    'Qtd_de_papeis' : 'Quantidade de Papéis:',
    'Valor_pago'    : 'Valor:',
    'Data'          : 'Data:'
}
columns = list(fields.keys())

sg.theme('Reddit')
layout = [
    [sg.Text(text), sg.Push(), sg.Input(key=key)] for key, text in fields.items()] + [
    [sg.Button(button) for button in ('Adicionar', 'Cancelar')]
]

window = sg.Window('Tela de Cadastro', layout)
headings = True
while True:
    events, values = window.read()
    if events in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancelar'):
        break
    if events == 'Adicionar':
        df = pd.DataFrame({column:[] for column in columns})
        df.loc[0] = [values[key] for key in columns]
        if headings:
            df.to_csv('registro.csv', sep=';', index=False)
        else:
            df.to_csv('registro.csv', sep=';', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
        headings = False
        df_new = pd.read_csv('registro.csv', sep=';')
        print(df_new)

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Show, serviu muito bem.. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).